# Proper sansfontoptions syntax

Tags: pdf, quarto

In my YAML header I would like to specify a hex color for the sansfont in my document however based on the Quarto documentation it's not readily clear how to incorporate the \fontspec options.

In the code below, I would like to set the sansfont to #ff7832, but I get the error

> "sansfontoptions has value text: |
> \fontspec[Color="#ff7832"], which must be a string"

I have tried both with and without quotation marks. Is there a different way I should be formatting this?

```
format: 
  pdf: 
    mainfont: Calibri
    sansfont: Overpass-ExtraBold
    sansfontoptions: 
      text: | 
        \fontspec[Color="#ff7832"]
```

I also tried to define a custom color, but did not have any success

```
 \definecolor{Foo}{rgb}{0.3,0.4,0.5}
 \fontspec[Color= Foo]{Overpass-ExtraBold}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the options of `fontspec` by listing them on separate line prepended by `-` , not the latex command.

````
---
format: pdf
mainfont: "Calibri"
sansfont: "Roboto"
sansfontoptions:
  - Color=ff7832
  - WordSpace=0.2
---

## This is Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a 
finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

## Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that
includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed 
code like this:

```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

---

[image: colored header done by setting the sansfontoptions]

---

And about the color code, as per the [`fontspec` documentation](https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf), p-26

> The colour is defined as a triplet of two-digit Hex RGB values, with optionally another value for the transparency (where 00 is completely transparent and FF is opaque.)

So simply use the hex color code (that is, use `ff7832`, not `#ff7832`).

Comment: Great thank you, this solved it. Is there also a way under sansfontoptions to distinguish between the title text and header text?